# Like Button and edge.create No Longer Returns Widget

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Anyone know whats up with this?

The widget variable is no longer being returned when clicking a Like button. As you can see in this Fiddle, the like button has an ID set. When the callback fires the widget variable is undefined though, has Facebook removed this var to stop people from tracking what buttons are clicked?

JSFiddle: http://goo.gl/rsvtuh

Comment: Official docs only say, _“edge.create - fired when the user likes something (fb:like). The response parameter to the callback function contains the URL that was liked”_ – and I can’t remember there ever being something about a “widget” variable in the docs. If you use features that are not in the official docs, please don’t wonder or even complain if stop working at any time.

Comment: @CBroe widget is documented and has been relied on by developers like me, in the past, and now that widget is not returned by the callback, existing functionality that some devs have relied on is broken: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is messing about with it's javascript API without updating the developers agains their breaking changes policy.

2 weeks ago i found out they stopped sending the widget parameter through the `edge.create`, breaking my app.

Today I found out they went back to returning the widget parameter only now it returns the dom element instead of a wrapper that holds the dom element, again, breaking my app.

In your case, Widget is now back, but you should be weary when using it. because it probably looks different now, and will likely change unexpectedly later.